# How to interpret upper-triangular matrix of cosine similarities

Tags: apache-spark, similarity

in Spark, there is a `RowMatrix.columnSimilarities()` method (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/RowMatrix.html#columnSimilarities()) that returns "*An n x n sparse upper-triangular matrix of cosine similarities between columns of this matrix*".

How should I read it? If I try to implement an example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1750187 as following:

```
JavaRDD<Vector> rows = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(
    new DenseVector(new double[]{2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1}),
    new DenseVector(new double[]{2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1})
));

RowMatrix mat = new RowMatrix(rows.rdd());  
List<Vector> sims = mat.columnSimilarities().toRowMatrix().rows().toJavaRDD().collect();
for(Vector v: sims) {
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

I get this

```
(8,[6,7],[0.7071067811865475,0.7071067811865475])
(8,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0.9999999999999998,0.7071067811865475,0.9486832980505137,0.7071067811865475,0.7071067811865475,0.9999999999999998,0.9999999999999998])
(8,[2,3,4,5,6,7],[0.7071067811865475,0.9486832980505137,0.7071067811865475,0.7071067811865475,0.9999999999999998,0.9999999999999998])
(8,[7],[0.9999999999999998])
(8,[4,5,6,7],[0.4472135954999579,0.8944271909999159,0.9486832980505137,0.9486832980505137])
(8,[6,7],[0.7071067811865475,0.7071067811865475])
(8,[3,4,6,7],[0.4472135954999579,1.0,0.7071067811865475,0.7071067811865475])
```

How should I interpret it? How do I get the cosine angle 0.822 from this, as mentioned in the referenced StackOverflow post?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to transform the matrix:

```
JavaRDD<Vector> rows = jsc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(
    new DenseVector(new double[]{2, 2}),
    new DenseVector(new double[]{0, 1}),
    new DenseVector(new double[]{1, 1}),
    new DenseVector(new double[]{1, 0}),
    new DenseVector(new double[]{0, 1}),
    new DenseVector(new double[]{2, 1}),
    new DenseVector(new double[]{1, 1}),
    new DenseVector(new double[]{1, 1})
));
​
RowMatrix mat = new RowMatrix(rows.rdd());
List<Vector> sims = mat.columnSimilarities().toRowMatrix().rows().toJavaRDD().collect();
for(Vector v: sims) {
  System.out.println(v); //(2,[1],[0.8215838362577492])
}
```